# PowerShell Script to copy files from one directoy to another

Tags: powershell

So I created a script to copy files daily from a directory and push it to another on our file server. So he store the files on the source as year\month\day i.e 2022\04\26\file.txt. I get the script to go into the latest day based on the variables provide and copy the file from the current day and push it to the destination. The only thing I can't get to work is copying the file, I get the error that the path don't exist although it shows up correctly. But if I add the path without using the variables it works as expect.

```
#Get Dates for Folder Creation 
$Timex = Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy_HHmm
$Timex1 = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$Year = Get-Date -Format yyyy
$Month = Get-Date -Format MM
$Day = Get-Date -Format dd

#Source files that will need to be moved
$APLogs = "C:\Logs\Stack3\$Year\$Month\$Day\Folder\_AP.LOG"
$ARLogs = "C:\Logs\Stack3\$Year\$Month\$Day\Folder\AR.LOG"
$NSLogs = "C:\Logs\Stack3\$Year\$Month\$Day\Folder\_NS.LOG"
$CSLogs = "C:\Logs\Stack3\$Year\$Month\$Day\Folder\_CS.LOG"

#Set the directory for the day
$TodaysDir = "\\FileServer\LOGS\LOG_DATA\$Timex1\Stack3"

# Test to see if folder [$TestFolder]  exists"
if (Test-Path -Path $TodaysDir) {
    "Path exists!"
} else {
    # Create Directory
    New-Item $TodaysDir -ItemType Directory

 }

   # Copy Log File 
   Copy-Item $APLogs -Destination $TodaysDir
   Copy-Item $ARLogs -Destination $TodaysDir
   Copy-Item $NSLogs -Destination $TodaysDir
   Copy-Item $CSLogs -Destination $TodaysDir
```

Error message = Copy-Item : Cannot find path `'C:\Logs\Stack3\2022\04\26\Folder\_AP.LOG'` because it does not exist.

Comment: have you tested that from inside the PoSh session? perhaps that session does not have permission to see the source file ...

Comment: Yes, I tried it and same result. I ran it in Powershell and visual studio code both as a user with full permission to the shares. If I remove the \$year\$Month\$Day\ and replace it with the 2022\04\26 it works fine. It seems like to dislike the data represented as variables.

Comment: AH! that makes things a tad clearer, thank you. [*grin*] ///// i think it would be worthwhile to test the variable version of the path to see if there are differences. for example, does the $var version look like `\2022\4\26`? note the missing `0` ...

Comment: Is `C:\Logs\Stack3\2022\04\26\Folder\_AP.LOG` a **folder** where files are that need to be copied, or is that the **file** itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPs code works just fine on my system when I tested it (which is why I removed my previous answer).

The code below is a cleaner way of implementing it.

*Note*: In the script (same as the original) there is an unused variable '$Timex'. Ensure that is not needed somewhere in the file path.

*EDIT:* After reviewing the error provided in the question, the folder path is exactly as expected. The problem is that the provided path is the wrong location. As there is an unused variable, made an assumption that it should be used instead of 'Folder' in $path.

```
$Date = Get-Date

$Timex = '{0:MM-dd-yyyy_HHmm}' -f $Date
$Timex1 = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $Date
$Year = '{0:yyyy}' -f $Date
$Month = '{0:MM}' -f $Date
$Day = '{0:dd}' -f $Date


$TodaysDir = "\\FileServer\LOGS\LOG_DATA\{0}\Stack3" -f $Timex1
$path = "C:\Logs\Stack3\{0}\{1}\{2}\{3}\" -f $Year, $Month, $Day, $Timex

# If path 'doesn't' exist, it creates it
if (!(Test-Path -Path $TodaysDir)) 
{
    New-Item $TodaysDir -ItemType Directory -Force
}

$Logs = @("_AP.LOG","AR.LOG","_NS.LOG","_CS.LOG")

foreach($x in $Logs)
{
    $log = "{0}\{1}" -f $path, $x
    if(Test-Path -Path $log)
    {
        Copy-Item $log -Destination $TodaysDir
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Could Not Locate: $log"
        $Error[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thank you very much for the answer, I tried all the requested changes and still for some reason stating that the directory does not exist. Is there any other way to everyday go into the /Year/Month/Day/xyz.txt and set that to a variable? Maybe I'm over complicating it, but that's the only way I can really think of.

Comment: What does it show the file path it's looking for in the error?

Comment: I tested both versions of code on my system and they worked without any errors. Ran it on Win10 with PS 5.1. What version of PowerShell and what is the OS?  

There is another way to get it in the date info in there. I'll edit my answer to shortly with how to do that.